# Apache Camel - Transaction error handler with dead letter channel functionality

Tags: apache-camel

I am in the process of developing a message router and I came to the point to deal with unexpected and put in place some error handling.

In my code I am able to distinguish when an exception happened because of a faulty message and this is the only one case that I would like to send the message to a dead letter end point.
In all the other cases I consider the exception caused by an infrastructure problem (e.g. a database/JMS end point became unavailable) in which case I would like to have the message roll back to the route start.

Looking at the Camel docs the only one error handler that supports dead letter is the `DeadLetterChannel` but the problem is this error handler is not transacted.

So is there a way to achieve what I want and how simple or difficult would be? I can see you can configure camel context to use a custom error handler builder and was considering trying to do a composition between the `TransactionErrorHandler` and and `DeadLetterChannel` in my own builder but I am not sure if that is the way to go. The out of the box builders seem to have  quite a bit of complex logic in there.

Another option would be to extend the `TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder` and bring the code from `DeadLetterChannelBuilder` that validates the end point and creates the failure processor but again not sure. If it was that easy the Camel guys would have included it in the framework. My use case must be anyone's use case that is dealing with enterprise critical applications.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions. Any hint would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I tried to to extend `TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder` as explained above and it did not work as the failure processor it creates is never used.

Because I really need this functionality I tried a work around by making my code add a **"dead.letter=true" in the message header and putting the original message back in the exchange like below:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    Message incomingMessage = exchange.getIn();
    try {
        // Do some work here
    } catch (MyCustomException e) {    
        incomingMessage.setHeader("dead.letter", "true");
        exchange.setIn(incomingMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exchange.setException(e);
    }
}
```

Then in my route definition I added:

```
from(ep).routeId(createRouteId(system))
        .autoStartup(false).transacted()
        .threads(route.getThreads())
        .filter(body().isNotNull())
        .process((Processor) routeBean)
        .choice()
        .when(header("dead.letter").isNotNull())
        .to(mq1:ERROR.QUEUE);
```

I expected that will solve my problem. However my ERROR.QUEUE did not get anything (nothing in the logs either) and the transaction committed and my message was lost.

Please help as I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Actually adding the endChoice() to the route above made the message delivered to the ERROR.QUEUE.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I have no idea why TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder can't be configured to send messages to dead letter channel.
And I was confused by its method `setDeadLetterUri()` that doesn't work as I expected. After long research I've found rather simple solution.

It process messages in transaction and if some exception throws, the transaction will be rolled back and the original message will be sent to the dead letter channel.
Please note, you should explicitly allow using of original message.

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    
    getContext().setAllowUseOriginalMessage(true); 

    from("jms:queue:{{foo.bar}}")
            .doTry()
                .to("direct:processMsgInTransaction")
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .process(exchange -> exchange.setMessage(exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()))
                .to("jms:queue:{{foo.bar.dead.letter}}")
            .endDoTry();

    from("direct:processMsgInTransaction")
            .errorHandler(new TransactionErrorHandlerBuilder() 
                .onExceptionOccurred(exchange -> log.error("Something went wrong")))
            //.transacted() //uncomment for using default TransactionErrorHandler
            .process(someProcessor)
            .process(someOtherProcessor);
            
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to address what I wanted. What I wanted was to have messages to `dead.later.queue` when encountering business exception `MyCustomException` when I know message is impossible to process (e.g. because is invalid) and rolback the transaction for any other exception.